# Outlet labeled "Non-GFCI" loses power when GFCI circuit is tripped

Tags: electrical, gfci

This is new construction, so it *should* be done to current code.  There is a 20A circuit for the garage receptacles.  One of the receptacles is a GFCI.  Another receptacle is for an on-demand water heater (gas-fired, but electrically controlled) and is specifically labeled **Non-GFCI**.  However, if the GFCI outlet is tripped, all outlets, including the **Non-GFCI** outlet for the water heater, lose power.  Is this correct?  They are obviously on the same circuit, but I would expect that the **Non-GFCI** outlet would be wired to not lose power when the GFCI is tripped.

**EDIT**
To clarify what I mean by "tripped", the circuit breaker is still on, but the GFCI outlet needs to be reset.  Also, the outlet for the water heater was specifically labeled as Non-GFCI by the electrician.  My guess is that this was done because it shouldn't lose power when there is a ground fault detected on the circuit.

As requested, here is a picture of the outlet.  When the GFCI is tripped, all outlets on the circuit lose power, including this one.

[image]

Comment: Despite what the label may say, it is quite likely **required** by code that a receptacle (plug/cord, not hardwired) for a device in the garage must have GFCI protection. Similarly, a device that is used near water (like, hmmm, a water heater!) must have GFCI protection - so that's strike 2. So it may well be that the receptacle is GFCI protected *because it is supposed to be protected*, notwithstanding any label to the contrary.

Comment: Are you sure it says that and not "GFCI Protected"?  It must say that if so.  Is the label hand written? Is this a simplex (1 socket) outlet?  Is this the only outlet that trips with the GFCI?

Comment: A picture of the outlet in question may help.

Comment: * My guess is that this was done because it shouldn't lose power when there is a ground fault detected on the circuit.* Actually, **NO**. The places where you deliberately do *not* provide AFCI or GFCI protection, where otherwise required by code, are **life safety**. That's the basis for a refrigerator receptacle not on GFCI (not formally in code, as far as I know, but allowed in many jurisdictions). It is also the basis for a fire alarm system and smoke detectors not on AFCI/GFCI (I believe that actually **is** formalized in code). And could be argued for critical medical equipment - e.g.,

Comment: if someone is dependent on ventilator or similar equipment then there could well be an exception allowed to say "not on AFCI or GFCI because the risk caused by a nuisance trip is higher than the small risk (if everything is properly installed and maintained) of an actual arc or ground fault causing any actual damage". But a hot water heater? No, just no.

Comment: What **does** happen is that certain types of equipment, due to old design or due to aging components, can be prone to causing nuisance trips of AFCI and/or GFCI. Then either the manufacturer *or installer* may decide to bypass AFCI/GFCI in order to avoid known (or *perceived*) conflicts. When such a thing is done (or even the refrigerator example above), the right thing to do is a single receptacle instead of a duplex, and that is indeed the case here. But what happened? My guess is that at some point the duplex GFCI receptacle was **replaced**, and the person doing that said "hey, why is

Comment: the 'load' set of wires pigtailed off of line? I *should* provide protection to the downstream receptacles." Which is often correct. But which should *always* have some investigation first. Because typically that is done so that hardwired ceiling lights are *not* on GFCI (they don't usually need to be). And in this case, would have found the single receptacle for the water heater and either (a) gone back to "NON GFCI" for the connection or (b) decided that GFCI was OK (as I think it really is here) and **removed the label**. So somebody messed up, somewhere.

Comment: Again, to be clear, this is brand-new construction that was recently inspected.  So, nothing was replaced or changed.  The NON GFCI label and single outlet were intentional from the start.  I'm only questioning if it is working as it should.

Comment: have you tried using a GFCI tester plug in that outlet, and seeing if it trips the upstream GFCI? (goal: distinguish whether this is a GFCI trip or an overcurrent trip)

Comment: @peter - no, I don't have a tester and haven't tested anything.  I was just surprised when the GFCI was tripped that the water heater lost power.  Maybe that is they way it is supposed to work, but I don't know (the reason for my question).  Am I maybe thinking about it backwards?  In that it is setup so that outlet can't be the cause of the fault, but still loses power in the case of a fault?

Comment: I highly doubt there is an approved GFCI exception for an on-demand water heater. Makes no sense, whatsoever. Which leaves 3 possibilities: 1 - The label should have said "GFCI Protected" and the installer was confused and used the label they would normally use for a legitimately **NOT** GFCI-protected refrigerator. **Change the label, problem solved.** 2 - The receptacle was intended (by water heater installer) to **NOT** be GFCI protected, but electrician didn't know and/or didn't follow directions and GFCI-protected it. **Change the label, problem solved.**

Comment: 3 - The receptacle was originally **NOT** GFCI protected, electrical inspector required it to be changed to be GFCI protected, but nobody changed the label. **Change the label, problem solved.** *By now, you should see a pattern and an obvious solution.*

Comment: Is it possible that plans called for a fridge there until some point in time when it was decided to put a water heater there instead (or also)?  Is it a point of use water heater?

Comment: The water heater is a tankless (on-demand) gas-fired water heater (Navien NPE-2).  The outlet was installed specifically for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That outlet looks exactly like it should if an exception has been granted in your building permit or inspection (check).  I don't entirely disagree with the idea - bonded copper pipe is pretty good grounding - but you want to make sure that sticker is approved and not a flight of fancy.   Also for aesthetic reasons, I would make another label and hand-snip the ends and move it down a bit so the label is entirely on the flat part of the cover.

GFCI receptacles have an optional feature called "Downline Protection".  If you do not use it, only the sockets are protected. Wiring this is very easy: attach all wires to "Line" terminals, and the instructions explain how to attach 2 wires to those.

If you do use Downline Protection, you can use this GFCI to protect additional outlets or points of use, by attaching them to the "LOAD" terminals. If this is done, the protected outlets >MUST< be marked "GFCI Protected" via any means not hand-written.  *This should never be done by default/in ignorance/by accident. To novices I advise "only use LINE".*

Unfortunately, most people who install GFCIs are *positively pathological* about always using Load for all onward wires, and hilarity ensues.  In their defense, the GFCI instructions advise doing this. But it's illegal if they don't label too.

People like using the downline protection because it's cheaper than a GFCI at every socket.

> However, if the GFCI outlet is tripped, all outlets, including the Non-GFCI outlet for the water heater, lose power. Is this correct?

That's *normal* if the GFCI is installed in the typical way, with all downline outlets wired to LOAD.

Circuits must be wired (well, *cabled*) in a tree topology.  Cables can branch but not loop (Britain excepted). Most circuits are wired in a species of tree called a 'vine' - a straight daisy chain.

If you want to defeat GFCI protection to this outlet, simply identify every receptacle in the circuit and replace them all with GFCI receptacles, and don't use "Load" terminals on any of them.  (Well, if you map out the tree, and you find several receptacles are past this one, you can use downline protection on that part of the circuit).

Comment: *bonded copper pipe is pretty good grounding* But at the price of copper, how likely is it that a new house has copper pipe?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'm not necessarily looking to change anything, but wasn't sure if it was working as designed.  Some other searching seems to show that this type of outlet is often recommended for these units as start-up could trigger a fault.  My assumption was the "non gfci" label meant that it wouldn't be affected when the GFCI outlet tripped.  But, I think what i'm hearing is that maybe this outlet won't cause a GFCI fault, but will still lose power when their is a fault on the circuit.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @user168671 GFCIs can't read :) If it trips when the GFCI test button is pushed, a ground fault there will trip the GFCI.

Answer (score 2):

New construction has a warranty period. Tell the builder you have an issue.

There was probably a mis-wiring issue.  It can be a simple mistake and easily missed on an inspection because the wiring was done to code... just not according to intended use.